# Linking MySQL C connector?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a **C++** program using **visual studio 2012**, **x64 release mode**, **Multi-Thread runtime library**. My project contains also the boost 1.55.0 library linked.

I am trying to somehow get the **MySQL C connector** (the C++ connector is poorly written so I decided to use the C) work. It works but I am experiencing random crashes and after searching around I believe the MySQL C connector is not linked correctly.

What I tried:

a) I donloaded the binary x64 for windows and I included in the library directories: `mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-winx64\lib\vs11`. I also added to additional dependencies `mysqlclient.lib`

b) I downloaded the source code, I compile it using:

```
cd C:\Users\Luka\Documents\mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-src
set MYSQL_DIR=C:\Users\Luka\Documents\mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-src
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -G "Visual Studio 11 Win64" ^
-DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=C:\Users\Luka\Documents\boost_1_55_0\boost ^
-DMYSQL_LIB_DIR:STRING=C:\Users\Luka\Documents\mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-src\lib
devenv.com MySQLCPPCONN.sln /build Release
```

I am really desperate, none of the above fixed the random crashes, **but the crashes don't happen if I remove the C connector from the project!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random crashes are most probably related to multithreaded use of **MySQL** client library. Try this

```
mysql_library_init(0, nullptr, nullptr);
```

before spawning any threads.

Here, more specific info from **MySQL** docs:

> In a nonmulti-threaded environment, the call to mysql_library_init()
>   may be omitted, because mysql_init() will invoke it automatically as
>   necessary. **However, mysql_library_init() is not thread-safe in a
>   multi-threaded environment, and thus neither is mysql_init(), which
>   calls mysql_library_init().** You must either call mysql_library_init()
>   prior to spawning any threads, or else use a mutex to protect the
>   call, whether you invoke mysql_library_init() or indirectly through
>   mysql_init(). Do this prior to any other client library call.

Comment: Hard to believe but I didn't even called this function once... I will add it. Also, I don't make calls from multiple threads

Comment: @Luka, I misunderstood your case. Thought you were using threads... I'm affraid calling this fuction won't help you much :( Crash debug info would be helpful in determining the issue.